# Why do I get so many captchas?

Tags: support, captcha

I am getting very frequent captchas when I use Stackexchange site that are not Stackoverflow. I haven't figured out a pattern but today I got a captcha when I tried to ask a question on tex.stackexchange even though I didn't post any other questions or answers beforehand. I also often get captchas when I try to use the search tool on stackexchange sites.

I am wondering if this is normal behaviour or if there is something  in my browser configuration (for example, Noscript, etc) that is making me trigger the CAPTCHA very often.